# PyAutoGUI の locateOnScreen を使った画像認識で、背景が変わると意図した通り動作しない

Tags: python, pyautogui

PyAutoGUIの画像認識にてパソコンの作業を自動化したいと思っております。

locateOnScreenにてデスクトップのアイコンを認識させることはできたのですが、
デスクトップの背景が変わると認識しなくなります。
grayscale、confidenceは試してますので、それ以外の方法はありますでしょうか？

```
import pyautogui
import time

x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon1.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.8)
pyautogui.click(x, y, clicks=2)

while pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon2.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.9) is None:
    time.sleep(1)

x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon2.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.9)
pyautogui.click(x, y + 50)
pyautogui.write('ID入力')
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write('パスワード入力')
pyautogui.press('enter')

while pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon3.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.9) is None:
    time.sleep(1)

x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon3.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.9)
pyautogui.click(x, y)

while pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon4.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.9) is None:
    time.sleep(1)

x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon4.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.9)
pyautogui.click(x, y)

while pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon5.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.9) is None:
    time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.write('1')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.write('3')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.write('4')
pyautogui.press('F12')

while pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon6.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.9) is None:
    time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.press('F2')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.write('1')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.write('03')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.press('enter')

while (pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon7.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.99)) is None:
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("icon8.png",grayscale=True,confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: 動かない状態で構わないので、現状のコードを質問に追記してください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。コード追加しました。方法はPyAutoGUIでなくても構いません。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 現状はこのコードで動きます。ただデスクトップの背景が変わると認識しなくなります。画像を2値化して認識させる方法などあるみたいですがどこにどう組み込めばいいのかわかりません。

Comment: 例えば1番最初のダブルクリックによる起動が出来ないということならば、こちらの記事を参考に実行させてみれば良いと思われます。[【Python】ショートカットファイル(.lnk)の正式なファイルパスを取得する](https://qiita.com/ZakkyR/items/38912749b132d966f7b9) 記事はスタートメニューのアイコンですがデスクトップならそのアイコンをシフトキー併押下の右クリックで出てくる`パスのコピー`で取得出来ます。ユーザー名が含まれるパスなら、ユーザー名までの部分を環境変数の`USERPROFILE`から取ってきてパス名を組み立てれば良いでしょう。

Comment: あるいは画像認識でやりたいなら、これらの記事 [How do I find an image on screen ignoring transparent pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71302061/9014308), [matchTemplate()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be) とかの応用でOpenCV等で認識して位置を取得するなどしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。一つ目のファイルパスからの実行できました。これで対応できる分はこれでやりたいと思います。対応できない分もありますので二つ目のほうもやってみたいと思いますが英語ですね・・・、がんばります。もし難易度が下がるのでしたら位置情報は無しで認識のみのやり方もあればお願いします。

Comment: ある程度進捗したなら、その結果(どれがどのように解決出来て何が残っているか)をもっていったん自己回答で問題を整理してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: すみません。正直に言いますとまったく進捗してませんし、まったく解決してません・・・。リアルタイムで画像を更新して背景に影響されない画像認識の方法を探してます。質問の仕方、説明が不十分でしたら申し訳ありません。

Comment: それは[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)ではありませんか？ 最初に思い付いた機能や手段にだけこだわるのではなく別の方法であっても実現出来れば良いと思われます。それでもPyAutoGUIにこだわるならその[Issues](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues)の中を探すとかそこに質問を上げてみるとか、考えを貫き通してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: すみません。言っていることがわからないです。再度説明します。まだまったく理解できてないのですが二つ目のアドバイスしてくれたほうと同じようなことをしようとしてます。バナナの画像と一致したときに実行したいのですが、背景の木が被ってるときは同じ画像として認識してくれません。

Comment: 二つ目のアドバイスしたほうを見れば分かるから解決したってことですかね。時間をください。がんばります。

Comment: 全てを同じ手段で一気に解決できなければならないと考えてしまうのは硬直的で先に進むのが難しいでしょう。代替手段によって一部でも解決出来たならその部分は解決済みとして、残った部分の解決に注力すれば良いでしょう。問題が限定的になって明確化すれば、ピンポイントで助言や回答を得られる確率が上がると思われます。

Comment: 一つ目のファイルパスからの実行できました。これで対応できる分はこれでやりたいと思います。たぶんこの言葉で解決したと思ってるのだと思うのですがこれは社交辞令的なやつです・・・。今回のではなく別の機会に使おうと思っているだけです・・・。このくだり無駄ですのでやめましょう。

Comment: あとはWindowsで動作しているプログラムが表示するウインドウならこちらが使えない場面は少ないと思われますね。[Pythonでウィンドウのタイトルから爆速で位置を取得【Windows】](https://qiita.com/ShortArrow/items/409f9695c458433d0744)

Comment: [How do I find an image on screen ignoring transparent pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302061/how-do-i-find-an-image-on-screen-ignoring-transparent-pixels)
の記事を試しました。1部エラーが出て`alpha = template[:,:,3]`の数字を3→2に変更したら動きました。理想通りの認識力です。
ある程度進捗しました。ありがとうございます。
locateOnScreenと違いリアルタイムの画像を保存しなければいけないのと次の動作への繋ぎが次の問題ですね。何秒更新してるのだろう？
自己回答で問題を整理してみます。

Comment: [Pythonでウィンドウのタイトルから爆速で位置を取得【Windows】](https://qiita.com/ShortArrow/items/409f9695c458433d0744)
こちらの記事はまだ試してませんが画像認識とは違いそうですのでまた別の機会に使いたいと思います。
背景が変わっても画像認識できるようになりましたので一旦このスレッドは終わります。
私の説明が下手な為に何がしたいのかをうまく説明できずにご迷惑をおかけしました。
また機会があればスレッドを立てたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: やり方が分からなかったのですみません。
kunifさんの[How do I find an image on screen ignoring transparent pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302061/how-do-i-find-an-image-on-screen-ignoring-transparent-pixels)
これがベストアンサーです。ありがとうございました。